# High charts - Increasing the space between chart and title

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I would like to know how to increase space between chart and the title. Similarly chart and the x axis title/legend. Explanatory image:

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the title properites. Check the API documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#title). You will have to mess around a little bit to get things how you want them but the tools are there. What you need are `x` and `y` and the chart spacing properties (see [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingTop)). The same applies to the xAxis title. One of the many great things about HighCharts is their API documentation. It is definitely worth a read-through.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for High Charts.

Take a look here for all the styling: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

```
title: {
    text: 'Title',
    floating: true,
    y: -30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple. You just have to set x or y property accordingly.
Eg:

```
               yAxis: {
                    offset: 30,
                    opposite: false,
                    title: {
                        align: 'high',
                        offset: 0,
                        useHTML: true,
                        text: 'y axis',
                        rotation: 0,
                        y: -10,
                        x: 48
                    }
                },
```

Refer this [API link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/title.x)

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to do the same thing and I found it simpler to use [`marginTop`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginTop) for this instead of `spacingTop` and title properties.

When you increase `spacingTop` you're increasing the space between the top edge of the chart and the content (including the title), which doesn't affect the space between the plot area and the title, so you still have to also set title properties to get that spacing how you want it.

Increasing `marginTop` increases the space between the top edge of the chart and the plot area, and the title seems to stay positioned relatively close to the top of the chart, so it increases the space between the title and the plot area without setting any title properties.